# How to get ip address of client in blazeDS

Tags: java, apache-flex, ip-address, blazeds

I am using blazeDS remote object. I need to get a client ip address from clien request. Is it any way to get ip address and system information in blazeDS java.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
FlexClient flexClient = FlexContext.getFlexClient();
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = FlexContext.getHttpRequest();
String clientIP = httpRequest.getRemoteAddr();
```

Regards,